# SSO login dialog returns to fbDidNotLogin with no indication of error

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I have recently created a new Facebook app ID as I'm adding Facebook SSO integration into my app. My app within Facebook is set to Native iOS and I've included the Bundle ID and a current published app's Apple ID (for testing).

I've implemented the SDK as per the instructions (I have two other iOS apps currently using the SDK without issue as well). All delegate methods and required plist entries are in place for the URL callbacks.

After attempting a login I'm shown the Facebook white screen (just a loading spinner) with blue bar but after 5 seconds it redirects back to my app and hits the fbDidNotLogin delegate method. That method doesn't include any sort of retrievable error (at least none that is documented or available to me).

So at this point I'm at a loss for what might be causing my login to fail. Is there any way to get a more detailed error? Or has anybody else run into this same problem?

Comment: Also having the same issue with no luck. Same SDK, same code, even using the same app ID as another app :/

Comment: I logged this bug in Facebook's system, if you want to add your reproduction steps to it maybe it will get addressed faster:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/247523252018539

Comment: I had the same problem. For me it didn't like that my iPod had the date set to 1970-01-01, which it sets itself to in spite, because of certificate expiration. Setting the date to the current date fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Solved this by changing two items in the Facebook app settings:

1. Configured for iOS SSO set to enabled
2. Updated the iOS Bundle ID so that it matched by bundle ID exactly (previously the casing was different)

Not sure which item fixed it, I largely suspect the first...but worth checking both.

Comment: Facebook says somewhere it might take a little while for those settings to propagate, but I guess you already had them set correctly, so that can't be it.

Comment: It magically finally started working, which is pretty frustrating :)

Comment: Not surprised. Facebook is so frustrating. Really hoping for proper system integration in the next SDK!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device's time and date settings are correct. I had this happen to me when I recharged and turned on an iPod whose battery had died. The date and time were totally wrong, and when I set them to what they were supposed to be, I got the Facebook login dialog just fine.